# Querying Cassandra through php

Tags: php, html, cassandra, querying

I am trying to do a SELECT query from Cassandra Database through a PHP script.
The connection goes through php successfully. This is the query:

```
$session  = $cluster->connect($keyspace);    
$result = $session->execute("SELECT * FROM twitter.tweets_by_author WHERE author= 'John Doe'")
```

**Question 1**

I will get the author name through an HTML form , let the variable be *author_name*. How do I pass *author_name* in the WHERE clause?

I have tried:

```
$result = $session->execute("SELECT * FROM twitter.tweets_by_author WHERE author= \%s\",author_name);
```

but this isn't working, most probably due to the fact that the value after *=* in WHERE clause needs to be in single inverted commas `''` for it to be valid cassandra query.

Further, I want to print the result, something like this:

```
printf("  \"%s\" \"%s\" \"%s\" \"%s\" \"%s\" \n  ", $row['tid'],$row['tweet_text'], $row['author_id'], $row['location'], $row['lang']);
```

**Question 2**
Since HTML will combine extra whitespaces how do I print whitespaces according to my wish?

Answer (score 1):

Answering Q1 only (I'm not HTML expert).  You better to use so-called prepared queries as it's [described in documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/php-driver/1.3/features/prepared_statements/).  Something like this:

```
$prepared = $session->prepare(""SELECT * FROM twitter.tweets_by_author WHERE author= ?")
$result = $session->execute($prepared, 
      array('arguments' => array('author' => author_name)))
```

One of the advantages of the prepared queries is that they are parsed once on server, and then client send only the data for placeholders (`?` marks), not the full query.  This gives very big performance boost. But **you need to store** prepared query somewhere, so it will be reused by multiple requests - it requires an additional roundtrip to server...